# Comaparing a variable inside a loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to compare for some duplicate value inside a loop because I need to do some logic. My problem is that I can't get the output that I expected.

```
var tempVal;
for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    var items = obj[i];
    tempVal = items.fund;
    console.log(tempVal); 
    console.log(tempVal == tempVal); 
    if(tempVal == tempVal){
        //do something
    }
```

In my example I have 2 same value in `tempVal` variable. My `console.log(tempVal == tempVal)` returns **`true`** in first loop but I thought it would return `null` or `undefined` in first loop because there's nothing to compare because it's empty on the first loop. What I need is top first return `false` then `true`. Thanks

Comment: it will return true because they are one and the same. name it another var then compare

Comment: `tempVal == tempVal` should be `true` for every possible value of `tempVal` except `NaN`. I don't understand why you would compare it to itself, or why you would think "there's nothing to compare" given you assign `tempVal = items.fund`. A variable can't be "empty", though it can have the value `undefined`, but if your `tempVal` was `undefined` then `tempVal == tempVal` would be `true`. Perhaps you could explain what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't explain it right. Here. How would I know if items.fund have the same value for every loop? For example on the first loop items.fund is equal to "TEST", the second is "TEST2", and third loop has "TEST" again. How can I filter that?

Comment: Are you saying you want a simple `true` or `false` result for whether every `items.fund` value is the same as every other one? Or that inside the loop if the current `items.fund` is different to the previous one then you want to do something with the current item?

Comment: @nnnnnn I want to check if items.fund value is same as every other one.

Comment: Can you give an real value and and result output that You expected?

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing the same variable, obviously they are equal, create another variable and compare.

```
 tempVal = items.fund;
 console.log(tempVal); 
 console.log(tempVal == tempVal); //both are same
```

Comment: How would I know if items.fund have the same value for every loop?  For example on the first loop items.fund is equal to "TEST", the second is "TEST2", and third loop has "TEST" again. How can I filter that?

Comment: you need to use for loop for that

Comment: @chiradee you need to use fol loop for the variable tempval and compare

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined the initial value. So obuse a variable compare with them self are always equal. Why are you not using another name for remove complexity also.

```
var tempVal;
    for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
       var items = obj[i];
       temp = items.fund;
       console.log(temp); 
       console.log(temp == tempVal); 
         if(temp == tempVal){
              //do something
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I thought this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
var src = [
  {
    "index": 0,
    "fund": 100
  },
  {
    "index": 1,
    "fund": 200
  },
  {
    "index": 2,
    "fund": 100
  }];

var tempFunds = [];
const uniqueFunds = src.filter(item => {
  if (tempFunds.indexOf(item.fund) === -1) {
    tempFunds.push(item.fund);
    return item;
  }
});

// logs the array with unique funds
console.log(uniqueFunds);
```

You can implement an `else` branch above if you want to deal with duplicate fund(s). Although there is no issue with your choice to use a for loop, you could also consider `map` or `filter` function(s) based on your problem.